# Get Product Image From Order Collection

Tags: product-images

This was asked at least three times between Magent.StackExchange and StackOverFlow, but the provided solutions are just not working for me. What im trying to do is get the image of each of the items in the orders, I tried using                         `'image_url' =>  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')` as explained in the other answers but im always getting an empty object. I made sure the product have a thumbnail assigned from the magento admin. Everything else is working just fine for the item details, just can't get the image or thumbnail url.

```
protected function _retrieveCollection() {

    // get the customer
    $login_hash = $this->getRequest()->getParam('login_hash');
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('login_hash',$login_hash)
                ->load()
                ->getFirstItem();       


    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId() )
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');


    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection(); 


    foreach ($orders as $order) {   

        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $items_arr = [];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            //Mage::Log(print_r($item, true));
            $items_arr[] = array(
                    'id' =>  $item->getItemID(),
                    'name' => $item->getName(),
                    'desc' => $item->getDescription(),
                    'price' => $item->getPrice(),
                    'quantity' => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
                    'original_price' => $item->getOriginalPrice(),
                    'product_type' => $item->getProductType(),
                    'image_url' =>  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')
                );


        }

        $order_arr = array(
                'id' => $order->getRealOrderId(),
                'date_created' => $order->getCreatedAt(),
                'total' => $order->getGrandTotal(),
                'tax_amount' => $order->getTaxAmount(),
                'shipping_amount' => $order->getShippingAmount(),
                'subtotal' => $order->getSubtotal(),
                'shipping_address_id' => $order->getShippingAddressID(),
                'billing_address_id' => $order->getBillingAddressID(),
                'total_item_count' => $order->getTotalItemCount(),
                'items' => $items_arr
            );

        $varienObject = new Varien_Object();
        $varienObject->setData($order_arr);
        $collection->addItem($varienObject);            

    }


    return $collection;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $_product=$item->getProduct();
    //Mage::Log(print_r($item, true));
    $items_arr[] = array(
        'id' =>  $item->getItemID(),
        'name' => $item->getName(),
        'desc' => $item->getDescription(),
        'price' => $item->getPrice(),
        'quantity' => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
        'original_price' => $item->getOriginalPrice(),
        'product_type' => $item->getProductType(),
        'image_url' =>  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')
    );
}
```

Comment: actually i know now where the problem is, your solution and min both works, the problem is that the magento api filters the url from the returned json for some reason, im checking this out now

Comment: What about the load overhead when you load the product model each time?

Comment: @RintoGeorge you can also use  `$item->getProduct()`

Comment: @QaisarSatti I have tried but it's giving empty string

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 get Product Image By **ID** in Order, 
please follow the code after:

> 

```
 - $_item = $block->getItem();

 - $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 - $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

 - $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

 - $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
```

> 

Please view [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138348/34916) link. Hope to help you !