# Add image in order items view page

Tags: magento2.3, product-images

I need to add product image next to product name in
module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml page without using objectmanager which is a bad practice.

Comment: Order items view page means order success page ?

Comment: I edited my question, thank you

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110896/34579 - see this

Comment: @Torantomina, did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit 2 files for adding image to order view section for customer

Copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.phtml` to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items.phtml

and add:

```
<th class="col image"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Image')) ?></th>
```

Copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

and add:

```
<?php $imageUrl = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class)->init($_item->getProduct(), 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl(); ?>
<td class="col image 1" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Image')) ?>">
    <img src="<?= $imageUrl; ?>">
</td>
```

**Note:**

- `items.phtml` will add **thead** and `default.phtml` will add **td** to table
- You may need to adjust `colspan` for table!

Hope above will help!